# Internet connectivity with Domain Controller

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, domain, windows

We have a Windows 2008 R2 Domain controller and every PC on the network has the IP address of domain controller set under DNS settings.  Is it normal to have the Domain controller also be the DNS server and lose all internet connectivity to all of the computers on the network when the domain controller reboots?  I understand that DNS is a core part of group policy, but how can I make it so all the machines in my network don't lose connectivity when the Domain Controller goes down?  Do people normally have a backup/mirrored DNS or something?  Sorry I'm self-taught and this is how the existing network was setup, before my time.

Comment: I'm going off the assumption that you still want internet connectivity, without the need of a DNS server online in your LAN. Hence my answer to set the secondary DNS sever for the clients as an external DNS. You could make a second DC, but if they both went offline, you'd be back to square 1.

Comment: You should never have domain joined clients using a non-AD DNS server, @Stretch. The proper solution is to have more than one DC (it's critical after all) and run DNS on each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two Domain Controllers. both also DNS servers, clients configured to use both for DNS. That is how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  I read all over the place that external DNS should never be used as an alternate, worst case with 1 server, it should be the gateway.  Example: http://firelogic.net/best-practices-for-windows-server-dns-and-how-to-avoid-the-common-pitfalls/

I will be temporarily using my local network gateway as secondary DNS until I get a second domain controller (if any).

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal to have a DNS server on the DC.

To make sure that you're clients don't loose internet connectivity, apply a second DNS server IP in the network configuration (such as 8.8.8.8 for Googles DNS). This can be done either through your DHCP server (if you have one) or manually on each client.

Answer (score 0):

Typical configurations include at least two domain controllers. Domain Controllers typically act as the primary DNS servers also, so it's good to have your DC's first look at themselves, and then then the other DC for DNS. The same applies to client PC's.

**DC1**

- Primary DNS = 127.0.0.1
- Secondary DNS = DC2

**DC2**

- Primary DNS = 127.0.0.1
- Secondary DNS = DC1

**Clients**

- Primary DNS = DC1
- Secondary DNS = DC2

And perhaps set Google DNS (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 or OpenDNS) as a lookup in the DNS MMC Snapin on the DCs, though this is not required; it makes me feel a little safer.

Comment: You've told the OP how to configure the DNS client settings on the Domain Controllers but you haven't answered the question that was asked.

Comment: @joeqwerty I believe they have answered the question. They state that that typical configurations have at least two controllers, and then go above and beyond by showing how to configure them. To be honest, creating an answer and then going on to give negative comments on the others is in poor taste and, frankly, quite rude. Comments are meant to be for building upon answers and providing constructive feedback, not just a "You're wrong" statement and negativity.

Comment: 1. You edited your answer after my comment. You did not originally have the preceding paragraph. You simply listed the DNS client settings on the Domain Controllers and you didn't have the following section with the Client DNS settings in your answer. 2. If an answer is wrong we have a responsibility to tell the person it's wrong. 3. Manners be darned. I can answer a question or post comments in any way I see fit. I don't see anything particularly offensive in any of my comments.

Comment: You've got this backwards. 127.0.0.1 should be last on your DCs.  A quick run of the AD BPA on your domain controllers will confirm this.